# CVAT installation issue

Tags: docker, ubuntu, internal-server-error, cvat

I'm trying to install CVAT and I'm following this installation guide:
https://github.com/opencv/cvat/blob/develop/cvat/apps/documentation/installation.md#windows-10

I installed Docker and Git as mentioned in the guide.
Cloned the CVAT source code from GitHub repository.

After this, I tried building docker images as mentioned in the guide.

$ cd cvat
$ docker-compose build

The complete Output:

```
cvat_db uses an image, skipping
cvat_redis uses an image, skipping
Building cvat
Step 1/49 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 657d80a6401d
Step 2/49 : ARG http_proxy
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ea9c09815fdf
Step 3/49 : ARG https_proxy
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f89f44a5f8df
Step 4/49 : ARG no_proxy
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1b880afdbe43
Step 5/49 : ARG socks_proxy
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 363c0a550b77
Step 6/49 : ARG TZ
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bef9ff0b2b9d
Step 7/49 : ENV TERM=xterm     http_proxy=${http_proxy}       https_proxy=${https_proxy}     no_proxy=${no_proxy}     socks_proxy=${socks_proxy}     LANG='C.UTF-8'      LC_ALL='C.UTF-8'     TZ=${TZ}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 688cc1462f94
Step 8/49 : ARG USER
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 33042ece9638
Step 9/49 : ARG DJANGO_CONFIGURATION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 176f7ed3f807
Step 10/49 : ENV DJANGO_CONFIGURATION=${DJANGO_CONFIGURATION}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6f6922b72aea
Step 11/49 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-transport-https     apt-get install -yq         python-software-properties         software-properties-common         wget &&     add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/xerus-media -y &&     add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep -y &&     apt-get update &&     DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq         apache2         apache2-dev         libapache2-mod-xsendfile         supervisor         ffmpeg         gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg         libldap2-dev         libsasl2-dev         python3-dev         python3-pip         tzdata         unzip         unrar         p7zip-full         vim &&     pip3 install -U setuptools &&     ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ} /etc/localtime &&     dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata &&     add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep -y &&     add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/xerus-media -y &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Running in f84af309de6a
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release
Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release
Ign:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse all Packages
Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted all Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe all Packages
Ign:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse all Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Ign:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse all Packages
Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
Ign:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Ign:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main all Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted all Packages
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted all Packages
Ign:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe all Packages
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe all Packages
Ign:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse all Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse all Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse all Packages
Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main all Packages
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted all Packages
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe all Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse all Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse all Packages
Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main all Packages
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted all Packages
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe all Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse all Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse all Packages
Ign:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Ign:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main all Packages
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted all Packages
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe all Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse all Packages
Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted all Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe all Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse all Packages
Err:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main all Packages
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted all Packages
Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe all Packages
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Err:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main all Packages
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted all Packages
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe all Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse all Packages
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Service 'cvat' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-transport-https     apt-get install -yq         python-software-properties         software-properties-common         wget &&     add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/xerus-media -y &&     add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep -y &&     apt-get update &&     DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq         apache2         apache2-dev         libapache2-mod-xsendfile         supervisor         ffmpeg         gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg         libldap2-dev         libsasl2-dev         python3-dev         python3-pip         tzdata         unzip         unrar         p7zip-full         vim &&     pip3 install -U setuptools &&     ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ} /etc/localtime &&     dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata &&     add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep -y &&     add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/xerus-media -y &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 159.69.208.88 11371]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Service 'cvat' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-transport-https     apt-get install -yq         python-software-properties         software-properties-common         wget &&     add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/xerus-media -y &&     add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep -y &&     apt-get update &&     DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq         apache2         apache2-dev         libapache2-mod-xsendfile         supervisor         ffmpeg         gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg         libldap2-dev         libsasl2-dev         python3-dev         python3-pip         tzdata         unzip         unrar         p7zip-full         vim &&     pip3 install -U setuptools &&     ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ} /etc/localtime &&     dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata &&     add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep -y &&     add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/xerus-media -y &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script failed at this line of Dockerfile

```
# Install necessary apt packages
RUN apt-get update && \
.....
```

Something are blocking Docker from connection. 
So i guess you're using proxy and you don't provide proxy information to Docker. So it couldn't connect with internet.

Please see [docker proxy](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/)